# bind-keys with a macro for lambda functions

Tags: key-bindings, bind-key.el, lambda

I am trying to bind keys to a lambda function using `bind-key.el`. I have the following factor macro

```
;; taken from Emacs Doom
(defmacro cmd! (&rest body)
  (declare (doc-string 1) (pure t) (side-effect-free t))
  `(lambda (&rest _) (interactive) ,@body))
```

which creates a lambda interactive function. So at first, I tried using that to bind-keys with no success.

```
(use-package org
:bind (:map org-mode-map
("C-c C-f" . (cmd! (message "Test")))))
```

But then I get the error. `use-package: org-super-agenda wants arguments acceptable to the 'bind-keys' macro...`. I also tried

```
(bind-keys :map org-mode-map
     ("C-c C-f" . (cmd! (message "Test"))))
```

but then I get the error `command-execute: Wrong type argument: commandp, (cmd! (message "Test"))` when I press `C-c C-f`.

I then tried replacing `(cmd! ...` with `(lambda () (interactive) ...)`

```
(bind-keys :map org-mode-map
     ("C-c C-f" . (lambda () (interactive) (message "Test"))))
```

but then I get stuck in an infinite loop when executing the previous statement. When stopping with `C-g`, I find that I am stuck in a function called `prin1-to-string` with a seemingly infinite

```
(closure ((binding closure ((binding closure ((binding closure ... nil ... ...)
```

as an argument. I think the reason is that in my particular file with lexical binding, closing the lambda expression is expensive.

How am I supposed to do this efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the format.

```
(bind-key KEY-NAME COMMAND &optional KEYMAP PREDICATE)
(bind-key "M-h" #'some-interactive-function my-mode-map)
```

`(bind-key "C-c iv" (lambda()(interactive) (my-function-here my-func-parameter)) my-mode-map)`

Documentation is your friend. `C-h f bind-key`.